# Adding var values to Google Charts ,angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

hey everyone am trying to display a chart of a data that am getting it from an API 
The Output of the API is `List<String>` not `Json` ;
here's my js file

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
packages: ['corechart'] 
});


app.controller("chartController",function($scope,$http)
    {


$http.get("/idcountcisco")
.success(function(data){

    $scope.cisco=data
    console.log($scope.cisco)


})


    $http.get("/idcountlog4j")
.success(function(data){

    $scope.log4j=data
    console.log($scope.log4j)


})
    $http.get("/idcountwin")
.success(function(data){

    $scope.windows=data
    console.log($scope.windows)


})



if (($scope.cisco=!undefined )&&($scope.log4j=!undefined )&&($scope.windows=!undefined ))

{

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                                  ['type', 'Qs' ],
                                                  ['cisco', $scope.cisco],
                                                  ['lo4j',$scope.log4j ],
                                                 ['windows',$scope.windows],
   ]);
var options = {
  title: 'Statistiques'
 };
 var chart = new    google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));

 chart.draw(data, options);

}

});
```

okey so in console.log am getting this

```
$scope.cisco=18
$scope.log4j=45
$scope.windows=15
```

and am having a chart like this , it's like it's not getting the real value when i tried to understand it after the `if` all my vars value become equal to true

thanks for any help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have two issues in your code:

**First issue:**

`not equal` is `!=` not `=!`, in your code you did `$scope.cisco=!undefined` this will set `true` to `$scope.cisco` that is '!undefined', so this is the first problem where your if condition will be true all the time.

it should be `if (($scope.cisco!=undefined )&&($scope.log4j!=undefined )&&($scope.windows!=undefined ))` or you can use `angular.isUndefined` for checking the variable is undefined or not.

**Second issue:**

As you are doing all `$http.get` in your controller and before all the `$http.get` executes you are going to drawing chart, `$http.get` will give you the promise where it runs in async mode so you don't have granted that when your are going to your if condition all the get request are executed completely , so this is your second problem , you need to fix it.

Comment: but  am using that condition so it can timeout until it gets the data

Comment: but your conditions are not correct , it should be `!=` not `=!`

Comment: yes i fixed it thank you , just asking with that condition that i just fixed ,  if i wont include promises  it should work right ?